# LINQ, can't join to string

Tags: .net, linq, c#-4.0, join

I have a list of users, each user has list of questions. In my model list of questions should be in string via comma. I try:

```
public List<ITW2012Mobile.ViewModels.AdminSurveyReportModel> SurveyReportList()
{
    var q = from i in _dbContext.Users
            where i.UserId != null
            select new ITW2012Mobile.ViewModels.AdminSurveyReportModel()
            {
                FirstName = i.FirstName,
                LastName = i.LastName,
                Question4 = String.Join(", " , (from a in _dbContext.MultipleQuestions where a.MultipleQuestionType.KEY == MultipleQuestionKeys.BENEFITS select a.Question).ToArray())
            };
    return q.ToList();
}

public class AdminSurveyReportModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Question4 { get; set; }
}
```

of course, I get error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Join(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression.

How to get it correctly?

Comment: instead of joining in `linq`, just return the collection and do the joining after retrieval

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would suggest doing the `string.Join` operation locally instead using `AsEnumerable`:

```
var q = from i in _dbContext.Users
        where i.UserId != null
        select new
        {
            FirstName = i.FirstName,
            LastName = i.LastName,
            Question4Parts = _dbContext.MultipleQuestions
                                       .Where(a => a.MultipleQuestionType.KEY == 
                                                   MultipleQuestionKeys.BENEFITS)
                                       .Select(a => a.Question)
        };

return q.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => new ITW2012Mobile.ViewModels.AdminSurveyReportModel
                     {
                         FirstName = x.FirstName,
                         LastName = x.LastName,
                         Question4 = string.Join(", ", x.Question4Parts)
                     })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Question4 has type String, your sentense with select has type IQuerable<String>...

Comment: @John: That's fine - because in `q` I'm only creating an `IQueryable<T>` for an anonymous type `T`. I only convert it to an `AdminSurveyReportModel` in the second part. I'll rename the property to make this clearer.

Comment: I need to add additional filter for `Question4Parts` before calling `.ToList()`, so I'm wondering about the performance of this query. Does it get the data only when it hits `.ToList()`? Or does it query as soon as it hits `.AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: @Hp93: It doesn't get the data until it's requested (which `ToList` will do) - but if you specify a filter after `AsEnumerable`, the filtering will be performed locally rather than at the database.

Comment: So if I want to optimize for the speed, I should write query to get `Question4` at the DB level, not by using `Join` in .NET, so that I can continue to filter on the DB after that. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @Hp93: We don't really have enough context to know. You should do as much filtering as you before `AsEnumerable`, but you could then still do the `string.Join` locally. If that's not enough information, I suggest you ask a new question with concrete details.

Answer (score 0):

can't include the string.Join() in the initial projection, because the LINQ translator doesn't support it. Can I write a custom translator for it?

Answer (score -6):

Try using the [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) method.

```
Question4 = (from a in _dbContext.MultipleQuestions where a.MultipleQuestionType.KEY == MultipleQuestionKeys.BENEFITS select a.Question).ToArray().Aggregate((x,y) => x + "," + y)
```

**Have not tested**

Comment: no, it does not work: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Aggregate[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.Func`3[System.String,System.String,System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.